# the oil prices for the period of 1980-2020

Tags: python-3.x

`import quandl oil = quandl.get("NSE/OIL", authtoken="UYaBJRd5SVGx9mKz_LbkYMDeao3FsFTw", start_date="1980-01-01", end_date="2020-01-01")`
AuthenticationError: (Status 400) (Quandl Error QEAx01) We could not recognize your API key. Please check your API key and try again.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow, please provide us a minimal reproducible example so that we can actually help you.

Comment: Oh and I don't think you should really copy the `authtoken` up with the rest of the code onto Stackoverflow. If it's something you're supposed to keep secret, this could be a security leak

Comment: @Eisverygoodletter idk im new to programming and i just copy pasted a code from a book i was reading.

Comment: ok, so basically don't. I believe this library is for accessing some oil prices from some server, and the `authtoken` is like your password / username for accessing the info. However, since it's from a book, it's likely that it's just randomly made up and fake. That's why there is an api key error: it's a fake key